# Can't set app-server to default values

Tags: json, rest, curl, marklogic, marklogic-8

I'm trying to reset an **app-server** from an **LDAP configuration** to default values at the **command line** using **REST** but it appears to not be working. The ***external-security*** element does not exist on the JSON or the XML marklogic properties webpage located on the 8002 port if it is not set.

```
http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/servers/App-Services/properties?group\
-id=Default&format=json
```

I think this might be a bug. I've tried null, 0, \0, [], and many other forms of null in JSON. The XML form does not work either.

```
curl -X PUT --anyauth -u admin:$(cat pass) --header "Content-Type:application/json" \
-d '{"authentication":"digest", "internal-security":true,"default-user":"nobody",   \
"external-security":"" }'                                                           \
http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/servers/App-Services/properties?group-id=Default
```

Returns:

```
{"errorResponse":{"statusCode":"500", "status":"Internal Server Error", 
"messageCode":"XDMP-VALIDATEBADTYPE", "message":"XDMP-VALIDATEBADTYPE: (err:XQDY0027) 
validate strict { $nsfix } -- Invalid node type: srvprop:external-security lexical value 
\"\" invalid for expected type #srvprop:external-security at 
/srvprop:http-server-properties/srvprop:external-security using schema 
\"manage-server-properties.xsd\""}}
```

Comment: Generally, object that don't have value are not set, have you tried creating external auth object first and setting "external-security" to that? https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/security/external-auth#id_35317

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Not setting the external-security element generates an error. I am rolling back from an LDAP configuration so the external-security element has a value. Not setting a value for it while removing the rest of the LDAP config generates an error because it still is defined: "If an external security is specified, authentication must be either application-level, basic or kerberos-ticket."

Comment: I think, for now, I'm going to delete the app-server and re-create it with curl. This will require a restart of the service but it will solve my problem. My thought is that if I need to roll-back from LDAP access controls, I have bigger problems then just needing local authentication. (IT will probably be OK to restart MarkLogic!) :)

Comment: `curl -X DELETE --anyauth -u admin:$(cat pass) --header "Content-Type:application/json"  "http://$HOSTNAME:8002/manage/v2/servers/App-Services?group-id=Default&format=json"`

Comment: `curl -X POST  --anyauth -u admin:$(cat pass)   --header "Content-Type:application/json"   -d '{"server-name":"App-Services", "group-name":"Default", "server-type":"http", "root":"/", "port":8000, "content-database":"Documents",  "modules-database":"Modules", "log-errors":false, "default-error-format":"json", "rewrite-resolves-globally":true, "url-rewriter":"/MarkLogic/rest-api/rewriter.xml" }' "http://$HOSTNAME:8002/manage/v2/servers"`

Comment: If it's in production before you delete, you can check if there are no pending requests against that app server via UI: http://localhost:8001/appserver-status.xqy?http-server=2861259732068689630&section=group&group=14318840029073230556 or via REST /manage/v2/servers?view=status